# $0 \cdot \infty$ object. Does it make sense?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

There maybe a mistake in the question but, let that someone asks you to calculate something like this: $$0\cdot \lim_{x\to0}(log(x))$$ with no further information. The assumptions that one makes is just that log is the natural logarithm, $x\epsilon\mathcal{R}$ and generally maybe some assumptions that a first year calculus course would assume. Nothing too complicated.

The question is the following: How do you somewhat rigorously attack this thing?

My thoughts:

If you see this as a whole is an undefined quantity of the type: $0 \cdot \infty$.

If you see it as parts you have a number $0$ and a limit that diverges. Since the limit does not exist (of course we implicitly assume that $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}$) we could not use the multiplication rule.

Hypothetically if we could use the multiplication rule we run into problems of what function's limit should we represent $0$ with. $x$? $x^2$? $x^{1/10}$?

What do I say then about this object? Does it even make sense to ask something like that?

Comment: Usually the question is about $ \lim_{x\to0}f(x)(\log(x))$ where $ \lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$.

Comment: Well the expression as you write is meaningless. Technically $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\log x$ is not something which can be manipulated like real numbers. Compare this with $\lim_{x\to 1}\log x$ which can be manipulated like numbers because this is just $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algebraic expression needs to have all its terms defined to have a meaning.

As

$$\lim_{x\to0}\log x$$ is undefined, the whole expression $0\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\log x$ is undefined.

And we also have $$(\lim_{x\to0} x)(\lim_{x\to0}\log x)$$

undefined, while

$$\lim_{x\to0}(x\log x)=0.$$

---

Also note that $0\cdot\infty$ is not an expression but an expression *pattern* which describes a limit of the form

$$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)g(x))$$ where

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0\text{ and }\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty,$$ as in my third example only.

Answer (score -2):

Generally $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is not to be taken as a number. This thing has no meaning by itself. The only meaningful expression is $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=y$, as a whole. Here $y\in\mathbb R \cup\{\pm\infty, \text{DNE}\}$. And $a \lim f(x)$ actually means "We already know that $\lim f(x)=c$ is a number, and we want to look at $ac$," plus some convenient edge cases involving $\pm \infty$. So your expression really has no meaning at all.

Comment: I don't quite agree. You might very well write $f(\lim_{x\to x_0}x)$. What is a special convention is to write $\cdots=\infty$ (as well as $\cdots\to\infty$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well then I guess it depends on the convention. My textbook unambiguously stated this at the introduction of limits. Anyway these definitions get you the same result ;)

Comment: Do you mean that $f(\lim_{x\to x_0}x)$ is not allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust As I said, it is a convenient shorthand for $c = \lim blah$ and _then_ $f(c)$.

Comment: @Trebor, you misinterpreted something, because, otherwise, we couldn't talk about continuous functions the way we do, at all. If $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists, then it is a number... Event if it doesn't exist, $f\left(\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} x\right)$ is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Croissant Well, I can just pass off every argument you have as being a "convenient shorthand", because convenient shorthands are exactly how we come to talk about anything the way we do, at all. For instance, the notation $c \in \{a,b\}$ is a (very) convenient shorthand for a tremendous amout of reasoning that certain sets exists, and $c$ belongs to them... Am I clear enough?

Comment: No, you aren't. What if $f$ is a multivariable function? Its limit, if exists, definitely isn't a number, but an ordered $n$ tuple...

Comment: @Croissant Since my interpretation allows almost everything yours does, I think it is pointless for extended arguments here.

Comment: @Croissant Well, you should not edit your comments except for correcting typos, because I will not receive notifs that way. In fact, many books on mathematical logic **ban the use of functions altogether**. The only legitimate thing is to say $f(x)=y$, as a whole. $f(g(x))=y$ is not legal, and should be translated to $g(x)=z, f(z)=y$. You can see an instance of this in Cohen's _Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis_. It is worth emphasizing that my approach is as strong as yours. It doesn't "exclude" interesting mathematics. So arguing over this is really worthless.